# AI/ML specialists - Where to find open source, medical data for creating AI algorithm which could diagnose glaucoma/cataract?

Tags: machine-learning, ai

I need to build theory for this school project - AI algorithm that could identify with some probability - glaucoma/cataract. My question is - where to get data? This should be existing data, preferably from some open source. The project assumes that we could for example cooperate with some research unit, basically we can assume anything that is within the bounds of common sense - this may be important - we play the role of company that produces Advanced OCT Solutions. We need to feed the algorithm with photos of healthy eyes and of eyes with glaucoma/cataract. And the photos have to be labeled. Any ideas guys?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/data/103477#595907 or https://web.archive.org/web/20210611172525/https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/data/concern/data_sets/3b591905z

Comment: There was a publicly funded German research project about combining text-Mining and DeepLearning of OCT imagery: [TOPOS](https://topos.averbis.de/) which had a few academic and commercial partners . Sorry the page is German only, and the [data](https://chemnitzer.linux-tage.de/2019/media/programm/folien/378.pdf) (s. slide 17) is not really open. Maybe you can find something there nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you guys. If someone has sth more, please comment :)